# QSortFilterProxyModel get Filtered Data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm pretty inexperienced with this kind of object in Qt and i need to know if there is a way to retrieve the data after filtering (for doing something with them, for example export in another file).

The situation is like this, i get data from a database and store it in a python list of list, after that i create a QTableView model and initialize it with a QSortFilterProxyModel set up for containing this data. In the interface there is a QLineEdit connected to the setFilterRegExp method, whose purpose is for searching through the data in the QTableView.

I need to create a button (or whatever) that writes a file with the data currently displayed on the GUI but i cannot figure out how to retrieve the currently displayed data.

Thank you for any advice.

```
class recordsTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

def __init__(self, records, parent = None):
    QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.__records = records

def rowCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.__records)

def columnCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.__records[0])

def flags(self, index):
    return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        value = self.__records[row][column]

        return value

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.__records[0]._fields[section]

class AndroidDialog(QDialog, ui_android_dialog.Ui_androidDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(AndroidDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.proxyModelContact = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.proxyModelContact.setSourceModel(recordsTableModel(self.contacts))
    self.proxyModelContact.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
    self.proxyModelContact.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    self.contactsTableView.setModel(self.proxyModelContact)

    self.contactsExportToolButton.clicked.connect(self.printData)

def printData(self):
    print "%s" % self.proxyModelContact.rowCount()
    print "%s" % self.proxyModelContact.data(self.proxyModelContact.index(0, 0))
```

for what i know the index should point at the item in the model (for me a table) so with this it should print the first item in the first column. Insteat it prints:
PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x02F7B030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowCount`, `columnCount` and `data` methods of the model attached to the view to access displayed data. In your case the model is a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Comment: Excuse me, but how do i have to combine them? I noticed that accessing the rowCount method after filter changes it's value (and that's good) but when i try to use the ".data" method error come up. I'll edit the post with some code to show what i'm doing.

Comment: What kind of error? Your code doesn't contain any usages of `data` method.

Comment: Sorry, i was still editing. Now it's not an error (wrong syntax :P) but now it prints on the console this: <PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x02F7B030>

Comment: `data` returns `QVariant`. You can use `toString` to convert it to `QString`.

Comment: Sorry for still bothering you, but i tried to place .toString in various place of the function and now says: built-in method toString of QVariant object at 0x0287F0F0 -  [for example self.proxyModelContact.data(self.proxyModelContact.index(0, 0)).toString]

Comment: `toString` is a function. You need to call it using braces just as any other Python function: `toString()`.